# Scale bubble in chart

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, jquery-svg

I have the following code modified from the kendoui demo

http://jsbin.com/alupin/6/

I am trying to scale the size of the bubble on mouseover and back to original size on mouse out however I am getting a trace of the border of the circle.

I am using kendoui to draw the chart and jquery svg to animate the svg elements.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border is added as part of the bubble highlight state.
This appears to be undocumented, but you can control the highlight border via an option:

```
{
    type: "bubble",
    highlight: {
        border: {
            width: 0
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

See it in action in the [updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/alupin/8).

I'll add this to the Kendo UI [Docs repository](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-docs).